# How to align my text with my star rating using html or CSS?

Tags: html, css

i used some code i found online to add a star rating to my HTML page but i can't for the life of me align it to a simple "rating" text to put all of them on the same line.

```css
.rate { 
    text-align: center;
    height: 46px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.rate:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
}
    
.rate:not(:checked) > label {
    float:right;
    width:1em;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#ccc;
    display: inline-block;  
}
.rate:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content: '★ ';
}
.rate > input:checked ~ label {
    color: #ffc700;    
}
.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    color: #deb217;  
}
.rate > input:checked + label:hover,
.rate > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rate > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
    color: #c59b08;
}
```

```html
<p>Rating: </p>

  <div class="rate">
  
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5" />
    <label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rate" value="4" />
    <label for="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rate" value="3" />
    <label for="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rate" value="2" />
    <label for="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rate" value="1" />
    <label for="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
  </div>
```

If anybody had a clue as to how to resolve my problem it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to fix  this is to place the p tag inside your div and then add inline-block and margin-top to the element as shown.   vertical-align:middle will not work on this.

```css
.rate { 
    text-align: center;
    height: 46px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.rate:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
}
    
.rate:not(:checked) > label {
    float:right;
    width:1em;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#ccc;
    display: inline-block;  
}
.rate:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content: '★ ';
}
.rate > input:checked ~ label {
    color: #ffc700;    
}
.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    color: #deb217;  
}
.rate > input:checked + label:hover,
.rate > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rate > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
    color: #c59b08;
}

p{display:inline-block;
margin-top:.8em;}
```

```html
  <div class="rate">
  <p>Rating: </p>

  
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5" />
    <label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rate" value="4" />
    <label for="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rate" value="3" />
    <label for="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rate" value="2" />
    <label for="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rate" value="1" />
    <label for="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `div` around it all and use good ol flexbox!!!

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.rate { 
    text-align: center;
    height: 46px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.rate:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
}
    
.rate:not(:checked) > label {
    float:right;
    width:1em;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#ccc;  
}
.rate:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content: '★ ';
}
.rate > input:checked ~ label {
    color: #ffc700;    
}
.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    color: #deb217;  
}
.rate > input:checked + label:hover,
.rate > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rate > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
    color: #c59b08;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <p>Rating: </p>
    <div class="rate">
    
      <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5" />
      <label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rate" value="4" />
      <label for="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rate" value="3" />
      <label for="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rate" value="2" />
      <label for="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rate" value="1" />
      <label for="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Maybe also explicitly state ```flex-direction: row;```, ```justify-content: flex-start;``` and ```align-items: center;``` (especially the last one).